# Шаблоны в MediaWiki

Tags: шаблоны, mediawiki

Создаю в MediaWiki с помощью "Управление TemplateData" простой шаблон «Шаблон:Тест» с двумя текстовыми полями Param1 и Param2:

```
<noinclude>
<templatedata>
{
    "params": {
        "Param1": {
            "aliases": [
                "Param1"
            ],
            "label": "Param1",
            "description": "Param1",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Param2": {
            "aliases": [
                "Param2"
            ],
            "label": "Param2",
            "description": "Param2",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "description": "Test1",
    "format": "block"
}
</templatedata>
</noinclude>
```

Создаю новую страницу: «Тест», добавляю в нее через VisualEditor «Шаблон:Тест», заполняю значения (Data1 и Data2) для этих двух текстовых полей.

```
{{Тест
| Param1 = Data1
| Param2 = Data2
}}
```

В результате страница отображается как пустая. В редакторе кода видно, что вставка шаблона присутствует. Подскажите в чем проблема? Предполагаю, что нужно указать «стиль» отображения этих полей, но как это сделать непонятно.

Comment: Вроде же через Visual Editor нельзя создавать шаблоны... или я пропустил какие-то новости? Как конкретно вы создали шаблон? Покажите код шаблона?

Comment: andreymal прошу прощения: шаблон создан через "Управление TemplateData", скорректировал вопрос, включив пример кода.

Comment: TemplateData всего лишь прописывает метаданные шаблона (и вообще прописывать их необязательно), а сам код шаблона должен быть написан вручную внутри тега includeonly, например что-то вроде `<includeonly>{{{Param1}}} - {{{Param2}}}</includeonly>` (подробности в [справке](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates))

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, все получилось. Добавил в шаблон следующий текст: <includeonly>
{| class="wikitable"
|+ Таблица с данными
|-
! Параметры
|-
| {{{Param1}}}
|-
| {{{Param2}}}
|}
</includeonly>